# Start executable jar with scripts on multiple operating systems

Tags: shell, applescript, executable-jar

I've written a program in Java and have a executable jar that customers will need to open on either a Windows or Mac machine. Some of my clients are ... not computer people.

Therefore, I need to write two scripts (if someone knows how to do it with a single script for both Mac and Windows, that would be amazing) to automatically start my executable jar with a double-click on both Mac and Windows. If Java is installed correctly, the scripts should work without any issues. If Java isn't installed, well, they should have known better.

This is my batch script for Windows machines:

```
start javaw -jar ExecutableProgram.jar
```

However, I'm unsure as to what kind of script to make for a Mac machine. **What type of script should I use?**

AppleScript? SH? **It needs to be able to execute with a double-click.**

Comment: Since the <executable> tag in IzPack doesn't work, it is not possible to have a script that, on double click, will run the executable jar. It is possible in Windows with a batch script, which is above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Mac OS X, double-clicking on a Jar should open it automatically.  However, I don't have a good way to test this; since I'm a developer, my computer does lots of things idiosyncratically :-)  In particular, Apple's own Java runtime is deprecated as of 10.6, and I don't know what tools come with other Java runtimes.  Nevertheless, if this approach works (as I think it will), it's the best bet.

If that doesn't work, the next best bet would be to use an AppleScript, like [adayzdone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11200013/237428) suggested.  The AppleScript that I would use would instead be this:

```
do shell script (¬
  "cd " & quoted form of POSIX path of (path to me) & "/.. ; " & ¬
  "java -jar ExecutableProgram.jar")
```

The `quoted form of ...` bit gets the path to the script (`path to me`), converts it to a Unix path (`POSIX path of ...`), and quotes special characters for the shell (`quoted form of ...`); since the script is running inside a directory, you also need the `/..` to get to the parent directory where the Jar is.  To make this double-clickable, copy and paste the text into AppleScript Editor, and in the "Save…" dialog, set the File Format to "Application".  (To edit it, open the application from inside AppleScript Editor.)  The downside of this approach is that you'll have two applications running: the true Java application and the Mac shell.  There are two ways around this:

- If the command-line output of the command isn't important, change the string on the third line of the AppleScript to `"java -jar ExecutableProgram.jar &>- &"`: `&>-` to close the output streams, and `&` to run it in the background.  (Just `&` won't work.)
- The more involved approach doesn't quit the AppleScript, just hides it:

  - Control-click on your AppleScript application and choose "Show Package Contents"
  - Navigate to the `Contents/` folder and open `Info.plist`
  - Add the key `LSUIElement` with value `true`:

    - If it's in a plain text XML format (not a binary one), you can add `<key>LSUIElement</key><true/>`
    - From the command line, this is `defaults write /full/path/to/Info LSUIElement -bool true` (note that you need the full path starting with a `/`, *e.g.* as obtained by using `"$(pwd)/Info"`, but you *can't* provide the `.plist` extension).
    - You can also use Apple's "Property List Editor" application, which (at least used to) come with the developer tools; free third-party property list editors exist too.

If that doesn't work, the absolute simplest approach to this sort of thing is to write a Unix shell script instead of a Windows batch script.  It must be saved with the `.command` extension, and have its executable bit set (`chmod +x file.command`). The contents should be

```
#!/bin/sh
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
java -jar ExecutableProgram.jar
```

(In case you're unfamiliar with Unix shell scripting: the first line declares that this is a shell script; the second line enters the directory the shell script is in; and the third line performs the relevant action.) The reason this approach is less desirable is that it will open up Terminal (OS X's command-line interface); you'll get a window that will stay open until the script terminates; when the script terminates, said window won't (or may not) close; and Terminal won't quit by itself.  Thus, it's more obviously a second-class citizen.

Comment: Hmm, hopefully I can run the chmod command from IzPack to make the script executable, otherwise this won't satisfy the requirements. Thanks very much for the in depth explanation of both, though. Also, since the script is in the same directory, the cd command isn't required.

Comment: @CODe: Actually, `.command` files are run from the users home directory.  Double-clicking `foo.command` opens up a shell and runs (in that shell) `/path/to/foo.command ; exit`.  I suppose you could also use `java -jar "$(dirname "$0")/ExecutableProgram.jar`.  I've never used IzPack, but [the FAQ](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/IZPACK/FAQ+-+Frequently+asked+questions#FAQ-Frequentlyaskedquestions-MacOSXExternalPackages) seems to indicate that you can use `<executable type="bin" stage="..." targetfile=".../foo.command" os="mac" />` to make the file executable.

Comment: Ahh, I assumed it was similar to a shell script. Unfortunately IzPack is pretty buggy, I tried the <executable> tag and it didn't make the file executable, no matter what conditional variables I changed. Looks like the customers will have to just figure it out on a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am unsure of the java command, you can save this AppleScript as an application to have it run on a double-click.

```
set theFolder to quoted form of "/Users/CODe/Desktop/yourFolder"
    do shell script "cd " & theFolder & " ; java -jar ProfessionalMediator.jar"
```

You can also execute this in the Terminal through an AppleScript saved as an application:

```
tell application "Finder" to set theFolder to POSIX path of (file (path to me)'s container as alias)
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "cd " & theFolder & " ; java -jar ProfessionalMediator.jar" in window 1
end tell
```

Comment: This may be what I'm looking for, can this be saved to a file and run automatically on double click? Or does it need to be saved as an application first? Apologies, I know very little about AppleScript.

Comment: Also, the script will be placed in the same folder as ExecutableProgram.jar, so how would that look in comparison to the directory structure you used above? This program is being installed on different types of systems so I won't always know the directory structure.

Comment: If you don't save the script as an application you will have to run it from the script editor. There are two ways to enter the correct posix path. You can drag the target folder to the script (which is open in script editor) or as Antal suggests, -- set theFolder to POSIX path of (file (path to me)'s container as alias)